# SharePoint Online incorrect term store tag but correct guid

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy

Hi fellow sharepoint experts,

I'm baffled by a problem that arose when documents were copied from one site to another.
For some reason the migrated documents have the wrong label being displayed. I can manually correct it by changing the properties of the document but I can't see why it has the wrong label in the first place.
As an example, using flow, I've got the properties of source:

```
        {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedTaxonomy",
        "TermGuid": "1e51adee-a95e-40f0-abf9-4d098e96aa32",
        "WssId": 237,
        "Label": "Label1",
        "Path": null,
        "Value": "Label1|1e51adee-a95e-40f0-abf9-4d098e96aa32"
    },
```

and on the destination:

```
                    {
                    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.SharePoint.SPListExpandedTaxonomy",
                    "TermGuid": "1e51adee-a95e-40f0-abf9-4d098e96aa32",
                    "WssId": 46,
                    "Label": "Label1",
                    "Path": null,
                    "Value": "Label1|1e51adee-a95e-40f0-abf9-4d098e96aa32"
                },
```

Only WssId is different in the above - I am aware of a hidden list but its difficult see whats going on. Could the list be corrupted?

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WssId can be obtained from a hidden list at the root of site collection called "TaxonomyHiddenList". You can browse it on https://sharepointurl/Lists/TaxonomyHiddenList.

When you assign a value for a TaxonomyField, an item is created for the selected Term  in a hidden list called TaxonomyHiddenList in the root web of the site. The WssId is an Id of this item in the TaxonomyHiddenList.

So, after copying files from one site collection site to another site collection, WssId should be changed, because every site collection has own TaxonomyHiddenList.